# QGIS cloud, add map to a web page

Tags: qgis, google-maps, cloud-gis

Is it possible to add a map which is published to QGIS cloud, on another web page? As a script code, like customised Google maps for example

Comment: you can use <iframe> http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp

Comment: Thank you Mapperz, I tried a lot, not effectively, to make kmz files or saved the raster images to different formats so google my maps accept them. But with your answer you solved my problem, thank you again.

My question has been answered.